# What’s wrong with my mango tree?

Tags: diagnosis, fruit-trees, fruits

The mangos sometimes fall off, but most of them develop like a split right in the middle where it’s curved (dry, then it falls off). This did not happen last year.

We water it 2-3 times a week, enough to keep the soil moist every now and then.

[image: Mango]

[image: Behind the mango is perfectly normal]

[image: The mango tree looks normal I think?]

[image: Mangos :(]

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused my different things. My guess is too much water. I don't think a tree needs 2-3 times a week watering, [here](http://tropicalfruitforum.com/index.php?topic=5107.0) (reply #4) they advice to give a mature tree water only when it doesn't rain for 14 days.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. We have been going through intense heatwaves and dry weather here in California, so I thought it would be a good idea to water it even if it’s just a little. Every fruit tree in our yard has been suffering too.